# Unable to select vertices after entering anything besides object mode and edit mode

Tags: vertices

Blender 2.9
Hello, I am currently having a strange issue where for a couple of meshes, after entering anything outside of object or edit mode, I can no longer select the individual vertices.

This is before
[image: as seen here]

And this is after, both using Alt+A
[image: Text]

This only applies to the head directly itself; the hair and body are not affected at all.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that something was settin the vertices to auto hide. In another comment, I saw to go into one of the other modes, and then hit Alt+H, and that resolved my issue.